# Rebol 2 has a bug creating files in Windows 8

Tags: file, windows-8, rebol

It seems REBOL/View 2.7.8.3.1 has a bug that appears in windows 8 (or maybe it is windows 8 which has a bug).

When you create a file in root partition of disk C: it becomes invisible in Windows Explorer, Windows command line and whatever Windows program accessing C:\ folder, that file is in another universe for Windows point of view.

```
>> save %/c/a.txt "hello universe!"

C:\> dir

(no clue about a.txt)
```

But if you do a directory listing in Rebol/View console, it is there! and you can read it, load it and even delete it

```
>> ls %/c/    
$Recycle.Bin/ a.txt Users/ Windows/
```

The effect of this weird bug is you cannot open any file created from Rebol/View 2.7 with any Windows program, files created inside Rebol are only visible to Rebol. But this only happens with files created in root folder, if you create files in any other folder all seems to be ok.

```
>> save %/c/aeat/b.txt "hello universe"
>> ls %/c/aeat
b.txt
```

and also

```
c:\aeat> dir
13/04/2015  00:24    <DIR>          .
13/04/2015  00:24    <DIR>          ..
13/04/2015  00:24                16 b.txt
```

Comment: Which version of 2.7 are you using?  on 2.7.8.3.1.1, it causes Rebol to stop responding

Comment: This might be useful - http://www.ghacks.net/2013/11/23/display-hidden-files-windows/

Comment: I'm using 2.7.8.3.1 and no, it's not a problem of hidden files, I have all my folders set to show hidden files and full name with ext

Comment: I confirm that it happens on Win 8.1 x64. File cannot be accessed even from DOS prompt, cannot shown even with DIR /A:H (hidden files, or :S (system files) etc.)

Comment: Yes, the answer provided for endo64 it's the right one. It's confirmed, it is not a rebol bug but a windows bug, really windows is so lame, just like a kick in the ass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start Rebol as a non-administrator, it doesn't have write access to C:\ (or any other protected paths like Program Files, C:\Windows etc.), but Windows 7, 8 and 2012 transparently redirects read & write access to virtual store:

```
save %myuniquefilename.txt "test"
```

Search for the file myuniquefilename.txt and you'll find it under the folder:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\
```

Search for "Virtual store on Windows 8" or "roaming" on Google.

Comment: So let's say Rebol 2 has no such a bug, but Windows has a feature :)

Comment: exactly, windows is really defective by design ;-)